# React-native componente que necesita dos click para accionar una función

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

estoy desarrollando una app con react-native, tengo un componente que cuando carga pregunta a la bbdd el saldo de un user y luego mediante un input consigue la cifra que el usuario quiere recargar en la pasarela de pagos.

El tema es que el botón que envía a la pasarela de pagos solo funciona cuando cuando hago click dos veces en él.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import UserProfileForm from '../forms/userProfileForm'
import commonStyles from '../../styles/commonStyles'
import I18n from '../../i18n/i18n'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {setCurrentAmount, updateCurrentAmount} from '../../redux/actions/currentUser'
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'
import {api, services} from '../../modules'

let parseValue = 0
class AmountCounter extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state={
   amount: this.props.state.currentUser.amount,
   newAmount: 0,
   value: '',
   idOrder: ''
  }
 }

 componentWillMount(){
  this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus',async ({action, state})=>{
   console.log('ACTION ROUTENAME=>', action.routeName)
   if(action.routeName === "userProfile" || action.routeName === undefined){

    let amount = await this.getAmount()
    this.setAmount(parseInt(amount.data.data.current_user_amount))
   }
  })
 }

 componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({amount: this.props.state.currentUser.amount, value: ''})
 }

 addAmount(){
  console.log('CLICK')
  if(parseInt(this.state.newAmount) !== 0){
   this.setOrder()
  }

 }

 getAmount(){
  return api.getAmountOfUser(services.user(this.props.state.currentUser.id))
 }

 setAmount(amount){
  this.setState({amount: amount}, function(){console.log('NEW STATE AMOUNT=>',this.state.amount)})
 }
 setOrder(){
  api.setOrder(services.setOrder(this.props.state.currentUser.id, this.state.newAmount))
   .then((response)=>{
    this.setState({idOrder: response.data.data[0].id_order}, function(){this.props.navigation.navigate('transporterPayments', {amount:this.state.newAmount, idOrder: this.state.idOrder})})
   })
   .catch((error)=>{console.log('Error=>',error)})
 }

 sendToRedux(){
  this.props.onSetAmount(this.props.state.currentUser.id,this.state.amount)
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <View>
    <View style={styles.amountContainer}>
     <Text style={styles.amountText}>{I18n.t('profile.balance')}: {this.state.amount} €</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.amountContainer}>
     <Icon
      style={styles.amountIcon}
      name="plus-circle"
      size={30}
      onPress={()=>{this.addAmount()}}
     />
     <TextInput
      placeholder='Añade fondos'
      keyboardType='numeric'
      maxLength={3}
      style={{width:'80%'}}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChangeText={(value)=>{this.setState({value},
       function(){
        this.setState({newAmount: parseInt(this.state.value)}, function(){console.log('TEXT INPUT=>', this.state.newAmount)})
       }
      )}}
     />
    </View>
   </View>
  )
 }
}

const styles = {
 amountContainer:{
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderRadius: 20,
  overflow: 'hidden',
  height: 40,
  marginBottom: 20,
  width: 340,
 },
 amountText:{
  color: '#424242',
  fontSize:25,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  textAlign: 'center',
 },
 amountIcon:{
  color: '#1f1918',
  paddingRight: 10,
  justifyContent: 'center'
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({state})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 onSetAmount:(idUser,amount)=>{
  dispatch(updateCurrentAmount(idUser,amount))
 }
})

export default withNavigation(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AmountCounter))
```

Llevo todo el día con la tontería y no soy capaz de que lo haga en un solo click.

Comment: ¿Puede ser porque el primer toque oculta el teclado y el segundo es el que realmente manda la información?

Comment: Vas a tener razón, como estaba usando el emulador sin el teclado, no he caido en eso... gracias